# How do I change a UIButtons label, label color etc. from another view controller?

Tags: view, uibutton, title

In one view (main view) controller I have a UIButton that creates a new UIButton. When you make a long press on the new UIButton a new view controller (second view) is presented by presentmodalviewcontroller. In the second view I have a `UITableView` and in the first `UITableViewCell` there's a `UITextField`. What I want is that when you input something in the `UITextField` the new `UIButtons` title changes to that.

What I have done is to create a `NSString` in my app delegate. In the second view in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

I have used this code:

```
// Passing the TextFieldText to NewButton.
        iAppAppDelegate *AppDelegate = (iAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        AppDelegate.ButtonText = [TextFieldText text];

        iAppView = [[iAppViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"iAppViewController" bundle:nil];

        [TextFieldText addTarget:iAppView action:@selector(ApplyAllObjectsSettings) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

In the main view I used this action to change the new UIButtons title:

```
- (void)ApplyAllObjectsSettings {

iAppAppDelegate *AppDelegate = (iAppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[NewButton setTitle:AppDelegate.ButtonText forState:UIControlStateNormal]; }
```

It does however not work. Any idea of how to make this work or another way to do it, would really be appreciated :)

Thanks in advance :)

Update:

In my second views .h file I have referred to the first view controller like this:

```
@class iAppViewController;

@interface ButtonSettings : UIViewController < UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate > {

// iAppViewController
iAppViewController *iAppView;
```

in the .m file I have imported the first view controller

```
#import "iAppViewController.h"
```

And this is the code I use to call the action:

```
            [TextFieldText addTarget:iAppView action:@selector(ApplyAllObjectsSettings:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

And this is the action in the first view controller:

```
- (void)ApplyAllObjectsSettings:(id)sender {

[NewButton setTitle:((UITextField *)sender).text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

}

Comment: I know, we have been there before: Your question has nothing to do with Xcode.  I guess you need to learn the difference between an IDE and a programming language.

Comment: My bad. Any idea how to solve it? :)

Comment: Yes :) Also, have a look at my answer for your other question pls.

Comment: Ohh sorry hadn't seen you updated you answer... my bad and thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't working because you never actually pass the new text to the button. When you say

```
 AppDelegate.ButtonText = [TextFieldText text];
```

is set's the ButtonText (which I guess is an NSString) to the `UITextFields` current text, which is most likely empty. If you look at the docs or other examples, you will see that the selector for `UIControlEventEditingChanged` actually accepts one argument. This is the sender, so in your case, the `UITextField` which fires the event. Using it, you can access the entered text and you won't even need your `ButtonText` variable.

So change row where you set UITextViews target to this: (Notice the new ':')

```
[TextFieldText addTarget:iAppView action:@selector(ApplyAllObjectsSettings:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Then change your listener to this

```
- (void)ApplyAllObjectsSettings:(id)sender {
    [NewButton setTitle:((UITextField *)sender).text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

**Update:**

So as I said, the iAppView in your second view needs to point to the first view. One way of archiving this is by making it a property like this (in your ButtonSettings.h):

```
@interface ButtonSettings : UIViewController < UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate > {
    ...
    iAppViewController *iAppView;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) iAppViewController * iAppView;
```

And don't forget `@synthesize iAppView;` in your ButtonSettings.m file. Now, when you are creating the instance of `ButtonSettings` in your FIRST view, you can just pass the reference like this:

```
myButtonSettingsInstance.iAppView = self;
```

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work.... the action is executed but nothing happens.... but what strikes me is: how does ((UITextField *)sender).text refer to my TextFieldText variable in my second view?

Comment: Because as I said, this variable is passed in the 'sender' argument. Have you tried the debugger? Is the ApplyAllObjectsSettings called? And wait a minute: You said that the button is in your first view while the textfield is in the 2. view? So why do you create a NEW ViewController for 'iAppView' in the tableview? Shouldn't that point the the first, already existing view?

Comment: The ApplyAllObjectsSettings is called. Yes it should but unless I use the code         iAppView = [[iAppViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"iAppViewController" bundle:nil]; 
the ApplyAllObjectsSettings isn't called

Comment: My strong guess (another way of saying 'I am sure') is that you call the wrong ApplyAllObjectsSettings. See, the iAppViewController you create in your TableView hat NOTHING to do with the one holding your button. You need to pass a reference to the iAppViewController that is holding your Button to the TableView (instead of creating a new one), so you can set it as a target in [TextFieldText addTarget:...]

Comment: Okay I have updated my question explaining how I call the action. Would you mind taking a look at it :) I understand if you don't :)